# Powerful PC struggles during normal use

Tags: performance, gpu

I recently bought a PC with the following specs:

MOBO: ASRock Z97M Pro4

Chip: Intel i5 4670k

RAM: 16 GB RAM 1600MHz

Storage: SSD Samsung 840 EVO 250GB to boot the OS and 1TB HDD 7200rpm for data

OS: Windows 8.1 PRO

Chipset Cooling: Corsair H80I

Power Supply: Super Flower Leadex Gold 1000W

GPU: Geforce GTX 750ti STRIX OC edition

Case: Fractal Design Define R3

Monitor: ASUS PB278Q 27 inches 2K

The monitor is connected to the GPU using a display port and the screen resolution is 2560x1440.

Everything works just fine, and suddenly the mouse pointer moves very slowly (like the PC is performing something very demanding), and after 5-10 seconds it returns to normal. This is happening in a very random pattern. For example today it happened after booting the machine. Some other times it happens when I am using it for more than 2 hours.

I have to mention that nothing demanding is performed at that time or any time. I  only use this PC for surfing, documents, spreadsheets, programming and listening to music or watching movies. No video editing or any kind of demanding things.

The weird thing is that, while watching movies in Full HD, nothing happens. Everything is working perfectly.

PS: All drivers are up to date, the room temperature is ideal.

I also checked the HDD and everything is OK. No bad sectors, etc.. Also the Link Power Management inside Intel Rapid Storage Technology is disabled. In the power options the HDD never sleep(at least the one with the OS in it).

If it helps, the configuration above was having the same problem even without the GPU. I had it working with the onboard GPU (intel 4600) for 10 days until i get my GPU, using DVI port and screen resolution of 1920x1080. Same thing happened. I though that maybe the monitor is too demanding and the new GPU will sort it out, but I was wrong.

I don't know what the problem is, and i am afraid that something went wrong.

Comment: Surfing, programming and watching movies can easily all be very demanding.  Mouse problem almost NEVER have anything to do with the HDH (the HDD can die in the middle of using it and the mouse should still work - at least until the OS locks due to lack of the expected HDD).  Is anything other than the mouse point effected?  What does the Resource Monitor and/or PerfMon show you when things get slow?  Did this system EVER work right?

Comment: The only thing i see as a problem is the movement of the mouse. But its not only the mouse, the whole system becomes slow. At that time the cpu usage increases, sometimes to 15-20% and some others to 70-80. But for a very short period. Is there a way to better monitor it?

Comment: What's the CPU temperature look like?

Comment: "Is there a way to better monitor it?", yes use PerfMon with logging turned on.

Comment: I will tell you exactly when i go home but for sure it doesnt get over 50 celsius

Comment: CPU Temp: 34 celsius, MOBO temp 36-38, HDD Temp: 33.

Comment: Think i found the problem.. There is a well-known lag of the mouse when it comes to Windows 8.1!! All the articles i found online described the problem when the user was playing games. Some other articles talked about the Microsoft Arc mouse (the one i use). Now i have installed a second mouse(wired USB, my old mouse) and though is slower its not affected by the lag. Both mouse are running in parallel and whenever i get the lag with the Arc mouse i use the other and its ok..